# bash: ./create.sh: Permission denied, when try to build a stack

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I've created a user with AdministratorAccess policy, I can run `aws s3 ls` and it works perfect, but when I am trying to use a template in bash to build a stack with Cloudformation

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
--stack-name $1 \
--template-body file://$2 \
--region=us-west-2 \
--capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

If I try to build a stack within the directory that contains all the files with `./create.sh test testVPC.yml` and I got an error: `bash: ./create.sh: Permission denied`

I am trying to deploy a simple VPC:

```
Description: >
  This template deploys a VCP.
Resources:
  VPC:
  Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
  Properties:
  CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/24
  EnableDnsHostnames: true
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: chmod 755 create.sh

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your error is a bash error, not a CloudFormation error.
In order to run `./create.sh`, the linux/unix system you're on must believe that create.sh is an executable program.

```
chmod 755 create.sh
```

Additionally, in general the first line of create.sh should indicate which language interpreter to use, in your case, bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Although this may appear optional because on some systems, if that first `#!` line is omitted, it uses sh (or bash) anyway.